Your video upload timed out before it could be completed facebook graph api error
I am creating facebook video ads with google app script, for this first I have to upload video with this endpoint: "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v19.0/pageId/videos". complete code function is this:
function uploadVideoChunk(pageId, uploadSessionId, startOffset, videoChunk) {

    //return uploadFileFetch(pageId, uploadSessionId, startOffset, videoChunk)

    var url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v19.0/" + pageId + "/videos";
    var payload = {
      "upload_phase": "transfer",
      "access_token": page_access_token,
      "upload_session_id": uploadSessionId,
      "start_offset": startOffset,
      "video_file_chunk": videoChunk
    };

    var options = {
      "method": "POST",
      "payload": payload,
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    console.log('upload Video Chunk responseData = ',responseData)

    var newStartOffset = responseData.start_offset;
    
    return newStartOffset;
}

I am getting this error: Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again
could you please help how can I solve this.
Thank you
I am following this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing/#step-2--upload-chunks-individually
